# How to run a bokeh server without 'bokeh server --show' command?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I want to run a bokeh interactive application without using "bokeh serve --show" command. Instead, I want to use 'python script_name.py' syntax.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the project documentation:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server

server = Server(
    bokeh_applications,  # list of Bokeh applications
    io_loop=loop,        # Tornado IOLoop
    **server_kwargs      # port, num_procs, etc.
)

# start timers and services and immediately return
server.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

[bigreddot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069991/4089158) is correct, but the commands given there won't start a bokeh server by itself; you'll need an existing Tornado server running; so here's a standalone solution given in bokeh's docs in the same [section](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library):-

Here's the relevant section that starts the server. For the complete example refer to the [example code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.1.0/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py) from bokeh's documentation

```py
server = Server({'/': bkapp}, num_procs=4)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/')

    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```